# Selenium Dropdown menu; Unable to locate element

Tags: selenium, xpath, drop-down-menu, dropdown

i am trying to click on the menu item, but i couldn't find Xpath.
If I write xpath like this its working:

```
> PATH_FIRST_VLAN="/html/body/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/form-directive/div/div[4]/div/div/field-directive/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]";
```

but i want to write like this:

```
//*[@id=\"ae54ac40-b28a-4bbe-b46c-b4c682f41377\" and @data-status=\"true\"]//div[@class=\"ui-grid-contents-wrapper\"]/div[1]/div[@class=\"ui-grid-viewport ng-isolate-scope\"]/div[1]/div[2]//div[contains(text(),\"ethernet0/1\")]";
```

above code is working this area:
[image]

but i need this area:

[image]

[image]

i used `@id="1642416596226-1-uiGrid-0011-cell"` but doesn't work.

Comment: please share a link to that page or the full HTML of the page. We can not guess the correct locator based on your pictures.

Comment: sure, https://rapidshare.io/Z56/bhr.html

Comment: I don't see these elements there

Comment: Hmm, when i select the dropdown menu right click and inspector, i uploaded the above picture. Anyway thanks.

Comment: I suppose you need to be logged in, to see your menu?
Alternative would be to copy the relevant html-code via the inspect-tool and add that to your question.